# Ajax to PHP with json using arrays make ignores "echo"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I've been trying to solve this myself for an hour today and I can't figure out the reason. I'm currently updating my website with ajax to make it look more "smoother" at the same time as I'm learning js and jquery.

The issue I have now is that my basic jquery post form, which works for all my post requests, like login and update sql, doesn't work.

The new form is posting arrays (3 different inputs with the same name) so that I could create a basic html table with the information. Due to this, I needed to use json dataType instead. My previous script has been collecting the data with basic php echo statements. Now, the ajax form wont react on the echos anymore. Everything works besides from the response from php to to ajax form.

PHP:

```
    $offer = 
'<table border="2">
<tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>';

for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['product']); $i++){
$offer .=
'<tr>
<td> '. ($_POST['product'][$i]) .'</td>
<td> '. ($_POST['quant'][$i]) .' </td>
<td> '. ($_POST['price'][$i]) .' </td>
</tr>';
}

    $offer .='</table>';


try{
    require_once('db_connect.php');
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO offers (company, price_table) VALUES(?,?)";

$connect->prepare($sql)->execute([$_SESSION['company_name'], $offer]);

if($sql){
    $_SESSION['already_submitted'] = true;
      echo "1";
}else{
    echo "2";
}
}
```

The ajax form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sendoffer').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       url: 'THE_URL_To_File',
       data: $(this).serializeArray(),
       success: function(data)
       {
          if ($.trim(data) === "1") {
            $('#sendoffer').hide();
            $('#error2').hide();
            $('#success-window').css('display', 'block');
            $('#sendrequest').hide();
          }

          else if ($.trim(data) === "2") {
            $('#error2').css('display', 'block');
            $('#error2').html('Fill out all the fields');
          }
          else {
            $('#error2').css('display', 'block');
            $('#error2').html(data);
          }
       }
   });
 });
});
```

EDIT: I've encoded the PHP response with json_encode, it didnt' work.
EDIT2: The post form didn't post the information either. Seems to be a problem with the ajax script over all

Comment: You set your dataType to JSON but are echoing a string so it won't work. Either output a JSON object with json_encode in your php script (look up the documentation) or change the Datatype in your ajax call.

Comment: I did encode it with json, still didn't work.

Comment: And it wouldn't send the array correctly to the php script without json. Since it's a "for(i)" script, it complains about "nothing to count".

Comment: You shouldn’t do echo before the DOCTYPE

Comment: There is no doctype. It's a plain and simple php script. EDIT: This is the script that the ajax form is posting to. The doctype for the specific page is way back from here